# AttributeError exception while accessing COM DLL in Python

Tags: python, com, vb6-migration

I'm trying to convert a VB6 program to Python.  The existing code uses a COM DLL (also written in VB6), called "ThisDll.dll" in the code below.  This is built against a type library ("ThisTypeLib.dll").  In the VB6, ThisTypeLib.dll appears in the project references, and the code is as follows:

```
Dim oThisClass As ThisTypeLib.IThisClass
Dim oTemp As Object

Set oTemp = CreateObject("ThisDll.CThisClass")
If TypeOf oTemp Is IThisClass Then
    Set oThisClass = oTemp
    oThisClass.OpenFile(sFileName)
```

This is the code I have so far in Python:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import gencache, constants

gencache.EnsureModule('<GUID>', 0, 1, 0)

thisClass = win32com.client.Dispatch("ThisDll.CThisClass")
thisClass.OpenFile(fileName)
```

I've used `makepy.py` to generate a Python source for the typelib.  However, when I run the Python code, I'm getting an `AttributeError` exception for the `OpenFile` call.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If anyone's following this question, we've decided to give up on Python and use C# instead.